# Get running project module's path

Tags: maven, path, directory

I have a multi module project. In my test when each module is initiated I have to log the user dir of that module. I use

```
 System.getProperty("user-dir");
```

to get the module's path. When I perform maven install at parent project level. I am seeing the logs contain the path for the parent project instead of the child module. Example,

```
Expected:
TestParentProject (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject)
     module-A (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject\module-A)
     module-B (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject\module-B)

Actual:
TestParentProject (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject)
     module-A (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject)
     module-B (C:\Users\User.Name\IdeaProjects\TestParentProject)
```

Not sure as how to get the expected path to be logged.

Comment: Would be useful to know a bit more about what you are doing with the property.  Can you not use the built in maven properties like `${project.basedir}`?

Comment: The one you recommend is maven property. I am not sure as how to invoke that property in my test.